# How to fix the draggable function in a bubble chart with text inside?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm setting up a new bubble chart, and want to be draggable with abbreviated names inside every bubble. The draggable function works fine and the bubble(without) are shown in the correct position. But when I try to add text inside every bubble they are always shown in the top left corner. Also when I try to drag and drop the text doesn’t move(only the bubble).

[image]

I tried to append text and bubbles to nodes, but it doesn't work for me.

I use d3.v4 (https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js)
and (https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js)

Bubbles without Text inside - Works fine

```
  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "bubbles")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.Interest); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.Influence); } )
      .attr("r", function (d) { return z(d.bubbleSize); } )
      .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended))
      .style("fill", function (d) { return myColor(d.bubbleColor); } )
```

Bubbles with text inside. Bugs: not positioned correctly and the text doesn't move with the bubble while dragging

```
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('g')
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.Interest); } )
  .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.Influence); } )
  .call(d3.drag()
  .on("start", dragstarted)
  .on("drag", dragged)
  .on("end", dragended))
  ;



     node.append("circle")
      .attr("class", "bubbles")
      .attr("r", function (d) { return z(d.bubbleSize); } )
      .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended))
      .style("fill", function (d) { return myColor(d.bubbleColor); } )

    ;

    node.append("text")
    .attr("class", "text")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.Interest); } )
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.Influence); } )
.attr("dx", -10)
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(function (d) {
return d.shortName
}).style("stroke", "black")
      .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));
```

I expect bubbles with text to be shown in the exactly same position as the bubbles without text ,and also while dragging - to drag both bubble and text, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `g` element is already positioned (but see below for correct attribute) and handles dragging. Remove calls to d3.drag from the `circle` and `text` elements, also remove the `cx` and `cy` attributes from the `text` element.

Add `pointer-events: all;` to the `.node` CSS class. That allows the `g` element to handle all mouse events.

To correctly position the g elements use `transform` instead of `cx` and `cy` (which only apply to the `circle` element:

```
.attr("transform", function (d) { var r = z(d.bubbleSize); return "translate(" + (x(d.Interest) - r) + "," + (y(d.Influence) - r) + ")"; } )
```

The [d3 gallery](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) is always a great source of inspiration.

Comment: I removed "cx" and "cy" attributes from "text" element and d3.drag from "circle" and "text", but now dragging function is not working at all.

Comment: This solved the problem with position, but dragging function still doesn't work.

Comment: You will need to alter your dragging functions since now you need to move the `g` elements using the transform attribute.